# Create a function to allocate a dynamic matrix

Tags: c, function, matrix, allocation

I want to create a function in C that allocates a dynamic matrix; the idea is to allocate an array whose elements are pointers to arrays; if I want to do that in a function, what is the correct code?

this

```
f(***matrix)
```

or this

```
f(**matrix)?
```

I would say the first one, but I'm not sure. thank you!

Comment: Neither is a valid function prototype, and neither is a useful *function call expression* for such an allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
double **
allocate_array(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    double **array = malloc(cols * sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        array[i] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*array[i]));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < rows; j++) array[i] = 0.0;
        if (array[i] == NULL) {
             while (i != 0) free(array[--i]);
             free(array);
             return NULL;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: For consistency instead of `sizeof(**array))` I'd write `sizeof(*array[i])` (or as `sizeof` is an operator: `sizeof *array[i]`). Anyways plus 1, not at least for the inner clean up loop ... :-)

Comment: This *is* fairly nice, but the `calloc()` is misleading. There is no requirement for floating-point zero to be bitwise zero (much like `NULL` doesn't have to be bitwise-zero). The initialization done by `calloc()` is useless.